# External SSD doesn't appear on my computer

Tags: hard-drive, usb, ssd, external-hard-drive

I have an SSD and bought external enclosure USB 3.0 for it, but when I insert it in my Dell laptop (windows 10 os) it does not appear on my computer window although it was working fine with an older USB 2 enclosure.
When I ran Disk Management it appears as 'Disk 2, Removable E:, No Media' and on Device Manager there seems to be no problem showing.
I tried to open it on other laptop (windows 7 os) and desktops (windows 7 and 10 os) it works fine on that machines with this new enclosure.
Also I have tried to change drive letter in disk management and to update drive by search online but it doesn't work as well.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a USB 3 port?

Comment: Format the drive with **NTFS** type File System.

Comment: What type of enclosure is it?  May need to break out that manual.

Comment: My enclosure is one like this https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00TGU0NOS/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: Yes all my laptop ports are USB 3.0

Comment: "it was working fine with an older USB 2 enclosure": First, make sure the SSD is properly seated in the enclosure's SATA connector. If that doesn't work, the enclosure is probably faulty.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the SSD is beginning to develop some fault, in order to be able to get your data, please perform a SSD recovery and then format to see if issue is resolved. You can check the link below for guidelines http://www.latestsolution.com/2016/06/how-to-recover-files.html